# Imputing missing values in a given dataframe

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, null, percentage

Write a for loop which will remove all the features with 20%+ Null values and impute rest with mean of the feature.

I am expecting to check % of null values and remove those features having more than 20% null values present in them. For performing this step, you have to write a ‘for’ loop that calculates % of null values for that feature. And for remaining features which have less than 20% null values, impute those features with its mean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know other methods of finding the percentage of null values and then dropping them out. But the task is to use for-loop

Comment: What is the data structure you're using to hold your values?